# Multiple splashboardd processes causes springboard crash

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management

I have an app that I remove and install often, after a while, the springboard is not responsive. I found a process called "splashboardd" in device processes, and it is being duplicated each time I run the app. It looks like it causes memory crash... any ideas?

```
Name = splashboardd, PID = 229, ParentID = 1, StartDate = 2015-04-16 12:08:05 +0000, Status = 2
Name = splashboardd, PID = 235, ParentID = 1, StartDate = 2015-04-16 12:12:42 +0000, Status = 2
Name = splashboardd, PID = 239, ParentID = 1, StartDate = 2015-04-16 12:12:44 +0000, Status = 2
Name = splashboardd, PID = 246, ParentID = 1, StartDate = 2015-04-16 12:26:45 +0000, Status = 2
Name = splashboardd, PID = 250, ParentID = 1, StartDate = 2015-04-16 12:26:46 +0000, Status = 2
Name = splashboardd, PID = 257, ParentID = 1, StartDate = 2015-04-16 12:54:40 +0000, Status = 2
Name = splashboardd, PID = 261, ParentID = 1, StartDate = 2015-04-16 12:54:41 +0000, Status = 2
Name = splashboardd, PID = 266, ParentID = 1, StartDate = 2015-04-16 12:54:52 +0000, Status = 2
Name = splashboardd, PID = 270, ParentID = 1, StartDate = 2015-04-16 12:54:53 +0000, Status = 2
Name = splashboardd, PID = 274, ParentID = 1, StartDate = 2015-04-16 12:55:00 +0000, Status = 2
Name = splashboardd, PID = 278, ParentID = 1, StartDate = 2015-04-16 12:55:07 +0000, Status = 2
Name = splashboardd, PID = 282, ParentID = 1, StartDate = 2015-04-16 12:55:08 +0000, Status = 2
Name = splashboardd, PID = 286, ParentID = 1, StartDate = 2015-04-16 12:55:10 +0000, Status = 2
Name = splashboardd, PID = 290, ParentID = 1, StartDate = 2015-04-16 12:55:18 +0000, Status = 2
Name = splashboardd, PID = 294, ParentID = 1, StartDate = 2015-04-16 12:55:19 +0000, Status = 2
Name = splashboardd, PID = 299, ParentID = 1, StartDate = 2015-04-16 12:55:45 +0000, Status = 2
Name = splashboardd, PID = 301, ParentID = 1, StartDate = 2015-04-16 12:55:52 +0000, Status = 2
Name = splashboardd, PID = 305, ParentID = 1, StartDate = 2015-04-16 12:55:52 +0000, Status = 2
Name = splashboardd, PID = 311, ParentID = 1, StartDate = 2015-04-16 12:55:59 +0000, Status = 2
Name = splashboardd, PID = 314, ParentID = 1, StartDate = 2015-04-16 12:56:07 +0000, Status = 2
Name = splashboardd, PID = 318, ParentID = 1, StartDate = 2015-04-16 12:56:08 +0000, Status = 2
Name = splashboardd, PID = 322, ParentID = 1, StartDate = 2015-04-16 12:56:09 +0000, Status = 2
Name = splashboardd, PID = 325, ParentID = 1, StartDate = 2015-04-16 12:56:18 +0000, Status = 2
Name = splashboardd, PID = 329, ParentID = 1, StartDate = 2015-04-16 12:56:19 +0000, Status = 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Conclusion:** Adding a splash screen to the app solved the problem. It seems that as long as the app does not have a splash screen, the device keeps in memory the splashboardd process up to the point where it kills the device's memory and stuck the springboard.